# MySQL - Select row only if previous row field was 0?

Tags: mysql

I have a table as below:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `status` 
 (`code` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,`IMEI` varchar(15) NOT NULL
 ,`ACC` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
 ,`datetime` datetime NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO status VALUES
 (1,    123456789012345,    0,    '2014-07-09 10:00:00'),
 (2,    453253453334445,    0,    '2014-07-09 10:05:00'),
 (3,    912841851252151,    0,    '2014-07-09 10:08:00'),
 (4,    123456789012345,    1,    '2014-07-09 10:10:00'),
 (5,    123456789012345,    1,    '2014-07-09 10:15:00');
```

I need to get all rows for a given IMEI `(e.g 123456789012345)` where ACC=1 AND the previous row for same IMEI has ACC=0. The rows may be one after the other or very apart.

Given the exampl above, I'd want to get the 4th row (code 4) but not 5th (code 5).

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean previous row by datetime

```
SELECT * 
  FROM status s
 WHERE s.imei='123456789012345'
   AND s.acc=1
   AND (
  SELECT acc
    FROM status
   WHERE imei=s.imei
     AND datetime<s.datetime
ORDER BY datetime DESC
   LIMIT 1
       ) = 0
```

Comment: OP didn't mention PHP/prepared statements, etc.

Comment: Ok, pretty minor, but I'll change it.

Comment: I know - but I just thought they might not be familiar with that syntax.

Comment: @Arth this query will only work if the OP has only one row that he wants returned... what if he has more than one IMEI that meets the criteria of ACC = 0 then ACC = 1?

Comment: "I need to get all rows for a given IMEI (e.g 123456789012345)" suggests that the `IMEI` is passed into the query

Comment: but again thats the same imei... `what if he has more the one IMEI  that meets the criteria of ACC = 0 then ACC = 1?` aka what if there was an IMEI (453253453334445) that had an acc = 1

Comment: This example has just one yea but that doesn't mean that there isn't more than one in the actual database

Comment: Wow, then change the IMEI in the query or remove that section of the `WHERE` clause.. If the OP asks for results for a given IMEI, then I'll write a query that returns results for a given IMEI.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would approach this problem is much different from the approaches given in other answers.

The approach I would use would be to

1) order the rows, first by `imei`, and then by `datetime` within each `imei`. (I'm assuming that `datetime` is how you are going to determine if a row is "previous" to another row.

2) sequentially process the rows, first comparing `imei` from the current row to the `imei` from the previous row, and then checking if the `ACC` from the current row is `1` and the `ACC` from the previous row is `0`. Then I would know that the current row was a row to be returned.

3) for each processed row, in the resultset, include a column that indicates whether the row should be returned or not

4) return only the rows that have the indicator column set

A query something like this:

```
SELECT t.code
     , t.imei
     , t.acc
     , t.datetime
  FROM ( SELECT IF(s.imei=@prev_imei AND s.acc=1 AND @prev_acc=0,1,0) AS ret
              , s.code                                                AS code
              , @prev_imei := s.imei                                  AS imei
              , @prev_acc  := s.acc                                   AS acc
              , s.datetime                                            AS datetime
           FROM (SELECT @prev_imei := NULL, @prev_acc := NULL) i
          CROSS
           JOIN `status` s
          WHERE s.imei = '123456789012345'
          ORDER BY s.imei, s.datetime, s.code
       ) t
 WHERE t.ret = 1
```

(I can unpack that a bit, to explain how it works.)

But the big drawback of this approach is that it requires MySQL to materialize the inline view as a derived table (temporary MyISAM table). If there was no predicate (WHERE clause) on the `status` table, the inline view would essentially be a copy of the entire `status` table. And with MySQL 5.5 and earlier, that derived table won't be indexed. So, this could present a performance issue for large sets.

Including predicates (e.g. `WHERE s.imei = '123456789'` to limit rows from the `status` table in the inline view query may sufficiently limit the size of the temporary MyISAM table.

The other gotcha with this approach is that the behavior of user-defined variables in the statement is *not* guaranteed. But we do observe a consistent behavior, which we can make use of; it does work, but the MySQL documentation warns that the behavior is *not* guaranteed.

---

Here's a rough overview of how MySQL processes this query.

First, MySQL runs the query for the inline view aliased as `i`. We don't really care what this query returns, except that we need it to return exactly one row, because of the JOIN operation. What we care about is the initialization of the two MySQL user-defined variables, **`@prev_imei`** and **`@prev_acc`**. Later, we are going to use these user-defined variables to "preserve" the values from the previously processed row, so we can compare those values to the current row.

The rows from the `status` table are processed in sequence, according to the ORDER BY clause. (This may change in some future release, but we can observe that it works like this in MySQL 5.1 and 5.5.)

For each row, we compare the values of `imei` and `acc` from the current row to the values preserved from the previous row. If the boolean in the IF expression evaluates to TRUE, we return a 1, to indicate that this row should be returned. Otherwise, we return a 0, to indicate that we don't want to return this row. (For the first row processed, we previously initialized the user-defined variables to NULL, so the IF expression will evaluate to 0.)

The `@prev_imei := s.imei` and `@prev_acc := s.acc` assigns the values from the current row to the user-defined values, so they will be available for the next row processed.

Note that it's important that the tests of the user-defined variables (the first expression in the SELECT list) *before* we overwrite the previous values with the values from the current row.

We can run just the query from the inline view `t`, to observe the behavior.

The outer query returns rows from the inline view that have the derived `ret` column set to a 1, rows that we wanted to return.

Comment: +1 for using user defined variables.. more dynamic and can handle multiple cases... I do have one question though... whenever I use UDV i usually make them like this `JOIN (SELECT @prev_imei := NULL, @prev_acc := NULL) i`.. whats the difference between that and `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev_imei := NULL, @prev_acc := NULL) i` ??

Comment: Hugely overcomplicated in my opinion.

Comment: but it will handle things your query wont :)

Comment: In MySQL, the `CROSS` keyword is entirely optional; it has no effect on the processing of the query. In MySQL, `JOIN`, `INNER JOIN`, and `CROSS JOIN` are synonymous. My personal preference is to avoid using the `INNER` keyword, since it adds nothing. The `CROSS` keyword is basically ignored by MySQL, but it's a clue to the reader that the omission of the `ON` clause is not an oversight, we are intentionally "matching" every row to every row. (As a reader, whenever I see the `JOIN` keyword, I'm looking for an `ON` clause, or predicates in the `WHERE` clause.)

Comment: Ah thanks :) I knew it wasn't really doing anything different but it is a good practice to write things similar.. thanks!

Comment: As written, it handles the exact same thing as my query.. the approach however is possibly more flexible. I would be interested to see which is faster on larger sets.

Comment: @Arth it handles your query and my query. not sure which would be faster on larger sets though :)

Comment: I was reviewing, and noticed that the ACC=0 row and ACC=1 row could possibly have the same value for `datetime`. I've modified my query slightly, to include `code` as a third expression in the `ORDER BY` clause. Absent that, we aren't guaranteed the order of the rows that have the same `imei` and `datetime`. Adding the `code` column to the `ORDER BY` makes the result deterministic. (It doesn't have to be the `code` column, we could order by ACC if we wanted the `ACC=0` row(s) to precede the `ACC=1` rows, when the datetime are the same.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from status s1
WHERE 
ACC = 1
AND code = (SELECT MIN(CODE) FROM status WHERE acc = 1 and IMEI = s1.IMEI)
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM status WHERE IMEI = s1.IMEI AND ACC = 0)
AND IMEI = 123456789012345
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.code,b.imei,b.acc,b.datetime
  FROM 
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) rank 
         FROM status x
         JOIN status y
           ON y.imei = x.imei
          AND y.datetime <= x.datetime
        GROUP
           BY x.code
     ) a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) rank 
         FROM status x
         JOIN status y
           ON y.imei = x.imei
          AND y.datetime <= x.datetime
        GROUP
           BY x.code
     ) b
    ON b.imei = a.imei
   AND b.rank = a.rank + 1
 WHERE b.acc = 1
   AND a.acc = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do a regular `IN()` and then `group` any duplicates (you could also use a `limit` but that would only work for one `IMEI`)

**SETUP:**

```
INSERT INTO `status` 
VALUES
 (1,    123456789012345,    0,    '2014-07-09 10:00:00'),
 (2,    453253453334445,    0,    '2014-07-09 10:05:00'),
 (3,    912841851252151,    0,    '2014-07-09 10:08:00'),
 (4,    123456789012345,    1,    '2014-07-09 10:10:00'),
 (5,    123456789012345,    1,    '2014-07-09 10:15:00'),
 (6,    123456789012345,    1,    '2014-07-09 10:15:00'),
 (7,    453253453334445,    1,    '2014-07-09 10:15:00');
```

**QUERY:**

```
SELECT * FROM status
WHERE ACC = 1 AND IMEI IN(
    SELECT DISTINCT IMEI FROM status
    WHERE ACC = 0)
GROUP BY imei;
```

**RESULTS:**

works with multiple `IMEI` that have a 0 then a 1... [IMAGE](http://screencast.com/t/rMjlNGNHOqu)

---

**EDIT:**
if you would like to go by the date entered as well then you can just order it first by date and then group.

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT * FROM status
    WHERE ACC = 1 AND IMEI IN(
        SELECT DISTINCT IMEI FROM status
        WHERE ACC = 0)
    ORDER BY datetime
) AS t
GROUP BY imei;
```